# Using cx_Freeze to Make First Program Into exe File

Tags: python, cx-freeze, setup.py

I made my first program (a gui calculator) in python using tkinter and am trying to use cx_freeze to turn it into an exe file. I'm really confused in how it works thought. I used cxfreeze quickstart in the scripts section of python33 to make my setup file. The program is named Calculator

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need
# fine tuning.
buildOptions = dict(packages = [], excludes = [])

executables = [
    Executable('Calculator.py', 'Win32GUI')
]

setup(name='Calculator',
      version = '1.0',
      description = '',
      options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
      executables = executables)
```

When I got to the console and type python setup.py build I get the error:

cx_Freeze.freezer.ConfigError: no initscript named Win32GUI

can anyone recommend a tutorial for using cx_Freeze or any other programs to make python code as exe format?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try `PyInstaller`. 
To convert a script to an exe file, you'd have to type something like this in a command prompt:

```
/path/to/python/pythonX.Y pyinstaller.py --onefile /path/to/your/script.py
```

Simple as that.

Comment: I got it, turns out I was designating the file to be launched from a GUI (mistaking the program for asking me if it WAS a GUI). Switched it to C for console runs just fine now